# How to get array with same key into one in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I would like to get the array with same value into one.

This is the array I have

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => role
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => role
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => category
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => category
        )   
)
```

This is what I want to achieve.

```
Array
(
     [0] => 5,
     [1] => 6
)
Array
(
     [0] => 4,
     [1] => 3
)
```

This is my code

```
$result = array();
foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
   $name  = $value['name']; 
   $result[$name] = array($value['id']);
}

foreach($result as $key => $val){
  print_r($val);
}
```

What I am getting is

```
Array (
    [0] => 5 
) 
Array (
    [0] => 4 
)
```

Can anyone here to help me for solving this? Any help really 
appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
$result=[];
foreach ($items as $value) {
    $result[$value['name']][] = $value['id'];
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
   $name = $value['name']; 
   if (!isset($result[$name])) {
       $result[$name] = [];
   }
   $result[$name][] = $value['id'];  
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: you can remove the `$key` since you are not using it.